# Programming Languages options for programming microchips/microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microchip, microprocessor

I am new to electronics.

I want to be able to build electronic projects on small handheld device sizes.

I am a software engineer, and I am aware there is a software part to an electronics project. And also if I am right after my researches it is called micro controller unit what I need to use as the hardware unit in my projects. There are a great variety of them from several vendors.

Can I use Lisp or SmallTalk running on the microcontroller for my electronics project? And if yes are there open source and free projects that can I use to be able to achieve this, and what are those?

Comment: Welcome, unfortunately your question is not really a fit here for two reasons.  First, the purpose of this site is for questions which can have *specific* answers, not those that seek a list.  Next, this site is only for questions where you've made some effort to find a solution by doing at least some trivial research on your own, not those where you ask people to give you answers so you can void doing so.  Your question is answered in thousands of places online, and already implicitly covered in numerous *existing* questions here.

Comment: Not quite what you asked but look at Arduino to start. You are unlikely to be sorry. Like simplified C++ / C. Can also run assembler and much else but starts in native mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programming languages for electronics engineers](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/programming-languages-for-electronics-engineers)

Comment: I have updated the question to be much more specific now.

Comment: I've never come across Lisp or SmallTalk on microcontrollers (although these may be available on some single-board computers, possibly).  C++ is probably as high of a level as it gets for the mainstream microcontroller languages, and a lot of microcontroller firmware is written in plain C.

Comment: By the way, come on downvoters, the question is now very specific, not too broad.

Comment: It seems to be a problem random viewers come and down vote a question, and never introduced a mechanism by SE to re review an improved version automatically. Probably they are all gone and do not know about updates  if not amongst the commenters or answerers. This could be a feature. I think I should post about this on meta.

Answer (score 2):

Any. Many. C, C++ are standard. Some can be done in Java, Basic, Machine code,  assembly. You could pay for other language compilers. What's available depends on the microcontroller you choose and how much money or effort you want to invest in it.

Comment: I have updated my question to be much more specific.